# express+mongoose get multi collection data and render to html

Tags: express, mongoose, promise

I want to do a blog,and I want to show article and tags in one html
this is what I do:

**route.js:**

```
router.get('/', auth.login_required, (req, res, next) => {
  let ctx = {};
  models.PostModel.find({}, (post) => {
  ┊ ctx.post = post;
  });
  models.TagsModel.find({}, (tags) => {
  ┊ ctx.tags = tags;
  });
  res.render('admin/dashboard', ctx);
});
```

but this way, the `ctx` has not things, it's `{}`
then I try this:

```
router.get('/', auth.login_required, (req, res, next) => {
  let ctx = {};
  models.PostModel.find({}, (err, post) => {
  ┊ ctx.post = post;
  ┊ models.TagsModel.find({}, (err, tags) => {
  ┊ ┊ ctx.tags = tags;                                                                                                                 ┊ ┊ console.log(ctx);
  ┊ ┊ res.render('admin/dashboard', ctx);
  ┊ });
  });
});
```

this can work, but I dont want to use nest query, how can I code it elegantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

render works even if the `find` methods returns an `error` , you should check if there is an error from the output.this way rendering the page only works if there is no error.

```
router.get('/', auth.login_required, (req, res, next) => {
  let ctx = {};
      models.PostModel.find({}, (err, post) => {
  ┊   ctx.post = post;
  ┊   if(err){
          //there is an error. 
           console.log(err);
           res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
      }else{
         //finding post completed 
           models.TagsModel.find({}, (err, tags) => {
        if(err){
         //finding tags gave an error.  
           console.log(err);
           res.status(500).send('Something broke!')
        }else{
         //finding tags completed
          ctx.tags = tags;                                                                                                                 ┊ ┊           console.log(ctx);
  ┊ ┊     res.render('admin/dashboard', ctx);
        }
  ┊ ┊ });
  }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your concern is only nest query then you can use [Promise](https://www.promisejs.org/) to chain your queries and get the result. You can also use the concept of embedded documents to fetch data.

As we know mongoDb does not have any concept of joins but this can be achieved by various ways

1) [Map-Reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/#MapReduce-Outputoptions) will also do what you need but your query might become little complex.

2) [$loopup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) allows one to combine data from multiple collections into one.

Also have a look at this [article which talks about joins in mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/#DatabaseReferences-DBRef)